# FourSquare check-ins problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foursquare

At FourSquare I am venue manager of below venue

https://foursquare.com/v/blue-label-labs/51127b9ce4b0fe8b7daf9dbb

this venue is located at Brooklyn, NY 11211, United States.

At this venue while any user checks-in from +5:30 Time Zone(venue time zone is -5:00) I does not get history any history of that user and also did not get that user in here now(API Service) also.

I want to get all check-ins from all over the world of any user at my venue.

Is there any time zone issue?
Any body can help me?

Comment: How is this programming related? Are you using any API to get this data? If it is foursquare API, you might be better off searching for answers at their support site.

Answer (score 0):

Foursquare doesn't allow you to check in to a location unless it thinks the user is actually nearby, so this probably has to do with the fact that this particular user is checking in from halfway across the globe. This also means that you can't really get check-ins from "all over the world" at a particular place.

For further app or product issues, please refer to [Foursquare Support](http://support.foursquare.com/home) and reserve StackOverflow for API or Platform questions.